# How to hide a div map if "p" tag is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to hide a div (`.map_toogle`) if a `p`-tag contains 'I have no Map', otherwise (`p`-tag is empty) I want to visible that div (`.map_toogle`).

I have following code but it always hide that `div` if `p`-tag is empty.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if($(".right_block p:contains('I have no Map')")) {
        $('.map_icon').hide();
    }
    if($(".right_block p:contains('I have no Map')")) {
        $('.map_toogle').hide();
    }
    if($(".right_block p:contains('I have no Map')")) {
        $('#camera_wrap_2').show();
    }
    if($('.right_block > p').is(':empty')) {
        $('.map_toogle').css("display", "block");
    }
    if($('.right_block > p').is(':empty')) {
        $('.map_toogle').css("display", "block");
    }
});
```

Comment: @Daniele94: Why the question? Given that the question is tagged with jQuery and jQuery is used in OP's snippet.

Comment: I want Jquary ,Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have multiple if checks while you can reduce it this way and check for the length:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   if($(".right_block p:contains('I have no Map')").length !== 0) {
      $('.map_icon, .map_toogle').hide();
      $('#camera_wrap_2').show();
   }
   if($('.right_block > p').text().trim() === '') {
      $('.map_toogle').css("display", "block");
   }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Why not:

```
$(".right_block p").text()!== 'I have no Map' ? $(".map_toggle").show() : $(".map_toggle").hide();
```

This is a simple if/else statement testing on whether the text within the `p` explicitly matches the string 'I have no Map' and showing/hiding the map div as a result.

That said, you may want to expand this into a regular full-fat statement as it looks like you're also performing a few other actions:

```
if($(".right_block p").text()!== 'I have no Map'){
    $(".map_toggle").show();
    // other actions...
}else{
    $(".map_toggle").hide();
    // other actions...
}
```

### However..

Generally it is best to code in as accommodating way as possible, what if you change the text indicating there is no map? As such, it may be better to test for the *inverse* (as long as you know this will be no text at all), and use:

```
if($(".right_block p").text()){ // ....no text present
```

Comment: May Thanks for the detailed answer but my fate its not working.I accepted above an  answer that was working well. And Again Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

This will do the trick

```
  if($('.right_block p').text()==="I have no Map") {
       $('.map_icon').hide();
    } else {
     $('.map_icon').show();
    }
```

You need to fetch the content using .text() which will return you the text